# Meteor recover password and change password

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new to meteor and I am trying to do recover password and change password in Meteor. I will post below  the code I have used to do this. I do get the template rendered, but the passwords do not change. Can anyone please help me with this? I am using the package `accounts-password`.

**Custom-useraccounts.html:**

```
<template name="RecoverPassword">  

    <form id="set-new-password">
      <label for="new-password">New Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="new-password" placeholder="Try not to forget this one.">

      <input type="submit" value="Set New Password">

      <p id="form-messages"></p>
    </form>

    <form id="forgot-password">
      <label for="user-email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="user-email" placeholder="Email">

      <input type="submit" value="Get Reset Password Instructions">

      <p id="form-messages"></p>
    </form>

</template>  
<template name="ChangePassword">  
    <form id="change-password">
        <label for="current-password">Current Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="current-password" placeholder="Current Password">

        <label for="new-password">New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="new-password" placeholder="New Password">

        <label for="new-password-repeated">Repeat New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="new-password-repeated" placeholder="Repeat New Password">

        <input type="submit" value="Update Password">

        <p id="form-messages"></p>
    </form>
</template>
```

**custom user-accounts.js:**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Template.RecoverPassword.events({
    'submit #change-password': function(event, template) {
      var currentPassword,
          newPassword,
          newPasswordRepeated;

      currentPassword = template.find('#current-password');
      newPassword = template.find('#new-password');
      newPasswordRepeated = template.find('#new-password-repeated');



      if (newPassword !== newPasswordRepeated) {
        template.find('#form-messages').html("The new passwords don't match!");

        return false;
      }


      if (Meteor.isServer) {
        if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
          Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
        }

        Template.RecoverPassword.helpers({
          resetPassword: function() {
            return Session.get('resetPasswordToken');
          }
        });

        Template.RecoverPassword.events({
          'submit #forgot-password': function(event, template) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var email = template.find('#user-email'),
                message;
            alert(email);

            if (email) {

              Accounts.forgotPassword(email);
              message = 'Sent a reset password link to ' + email + '.';
            } else {
              message = 'Please enter a valid email address.'
            }


            template.find('#form-messages').html(message);

            return false;
          },
          'submit #set-new-password': function(event, template) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Proper decoupled validation would be much nicer than this
            var password = template.find('#new-password').value,
                passwordTest = new RegExp("(?=.{6,}).*", "g");


            if (passwordTest.test(password)) {
              Accounts.resetPassword(
                Session.get('resetPasswordToken'),
                password,
                function(error) {
                  if (err) {
                    template.find('#form-messages').html('There was a problem resetting your password.');
                  } else {

                    Session.set('resetPasswordToken', null);
                  }
                });
            } else {

              template.find('#form-messages').html('Your password is too weak!');
            }

            return false;
          }
        });
      }
```

I have already removed the `insecure` and `autopublish` options and I have published the userdata. I just cannot understand why template to change password does not work.

Comment: One problem is that Session is client side only, so this code doesn't make too much sense: `if (Meteor.isServer){
if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {  
  Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is you're running that code on the server with `if (Meteor.isServer)`

All your client code needs to be in `if (Meteor.isClient)` which is anything template level. You also get that for free if it's in a folder called `client`.